# How to test auto periodic updates on the page using capybara?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I have one page where user can leave opened for a while. And javascript is making updates using setInterval. How could I test it?

```
Scenario: Auto update dashboard
  When I am on the dashboard page
    Then I should see nothing on the page

  When someone added item
    Then I should see a new item on the page in few seconds
```

I can put sleep to the 'someone added item', but is it good way to do it?
Anyway 'sleep' doesn't work for me for some reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara's has_content will automatically wait (you can decide for how much) for some content to appear, so you can have something like this (rspec syntax):

```
page.should have_content 'Update 1'
page.should have_content 'Update 2'
page.should have_content 'Update 3'
```

Of course it may be helpful to test for the state in between, but this may be good enough.

EDIT: I'm assuming the interval is very small, like a couple of seconds at most, otherwise your tests will run very slowly.